# node websocket-server -- ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, express

I'm using this with expressjs, is there a good way to catch this error:

> WS: 179575738318 end WS: 179575738318 stateChange:  4 -> 5 WS:
>   179575738318 socket closed WS: 179575738318 stateChange:  5 -> 6
>   Manager: Detached:  (11) WS: 179575734517 end
>   WS: 179575734517 stateChange:  4 -> 5 WS: 179575734517 socket closed
>   WS: 179575734517 stateChange:  5 -> 6 Manager: Detached:  (10) WS: 179575734515 error Error: ETIMEDOUT, Connection
>   timed out
>
> node.js:134
>           throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first
>   tick
>           ^ Error: ETIMEDOUT, Connection timed out
>       at Socket._readImpl (net.js:163:14)
>       at Socket._onReadable (net.js:633:22)
>       at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)

I add in this clause, so this should work?

> ws.websocketServer.on('error', function (error) {
>         console.log('Error: ' + error);     });

Comment: which module are you using for websockets?

Comment: websocket-server  : https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server

Comment: Which browser are you using to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ws.websocketServer.on('error', function (error) { console.log('Error: ' + error); }); did it.